# Looping Sortino Ratio in Matlab

Tags: matlab

This is the formula for Sortino Ratio in Matlab:

```
Sortino = (mean(Data) - MAR) / sqrt(lpm(Data, MAR, 2))
```

Can someone please advise how to run this equation on every single variable in my Matlab dataset (one after the other)?

My Matlab dataset is as follows:

I have approx. 1400 variables in columns, the number of data points depends on a variable. Thus, not all of them are the same (i.e. returns for various stocks).

Also, is it possible to get the output (Sortino's for all variables) in a Table?

PS. I had a look at various loop suggestions but could not understand a single thing. They are nothing like VBA or STATA.

Data Format (with NaN as empty cells):

[image]

Thank you
West

Comment: Could you please show a bit of your data (not all 1400, but just two or three). I do not really understand the structure of the data.

Comment: The data is in columns. Just like in the Yahoo Finance e.g. FTSE100 download.

Comment: I have never heard about this dataset and I'm not willing to google it. You need help on how to loop through your data. Thus, include an examplary snippet of your data. If you expect help, you should provide all necessary information. [Reading this might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm not sure which part of a "column" with numbers you don't understand. It's beyond explanation, really.

Comment: _It's beyond explanation, really._ Are the missing data in your columns `NaN`, `0` or something else? What is the `variable` the number of data points depends on? Is this variable used to select a subset of data points from your columns or are the data in your columns already adapted?

As you see, everything is self-explaining.

Comment: @PatrickHappel Understood. Photo added (empty cells are NaN). Every variable is individual and I need Sortino equation to run through every variable and save the output in a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll give it a try.

I'll use the data as shown in [the docs](https://de.mathworks.com/help/finance/sample-and-expected-lower-partial-moments.html#bqwfppx)

First, load it (you don't need to, you have your data already), but I haven't:

```
load FundMarketCash 
Returns = tick2ret(TestData);
```

Since you have some `NaN`s in you data, lets replace some values with `NaN`s:

```
Returns(end-8:end, 1) = NaN;
Returns(end-5:end, 2) = NaN;
```

As in the docs, let's use the mean of the third column (withou `NaN`s) as `MAR`:

```
MAR = mean(Returns(:,3));
```

No, let's try to compute the nominator of the Sortino ratio. Since MATLAB can operate on matrices, there is no need for a loop.

```
>> mean(Returns) - MAR

ans =

   NaN   NaN     0
```

Huh? The mean of the columns containing `NaN` is `NaN`. So, your true question might be "How to compute the mean of a column that contains `NaN`s?" The answer to this question would be  "Use `nanmean`".

```
>> nanmean(Returns) - MAR

ans =

    0.0019   -0.0002         0
```

Let's further check if `lpm` can deal `NaN`s by checking the first two columns:

```
% Copy columns to col1 and col2 for logical indexing
col1 = Returns(:,1);
col2 = Returns(:,2);
```

Test col1 with `NaN`s

```
>> lpm(col1, MAR, 0:2)
 ans =

    0.4314
    0.0084
    0.0003
```

and without `NaN`s:

```
>> lpm(col1(~isnan(col1)), MAR, 0:2)

ans =

    0.4314
    0.0084
    0.0003
```

Seems to be the same. Lets repeat it for `col2`:

```
>> lpm(col2, MAR, 0:2)

ans =

    0.4444
    0.0155
    0.0009

>> lpm(col2(~isnan(col2)), MAR, 0:2)

ans =

    0.4444
    0.0155
    0.0009
```

Also the same. Thus, let's assume `lpm` can handle `NaN`s.

So, you can simply compute the Sortino ratio in a one-liner:

```
Sortino = (nanmean(Returns) - MAR) ./ sqrt(lpm(Returns, MAR, 2))

Sortino =

    0.1077   -0.0053         0
```

Comment: Thanks, Patric, I'll try it for a larger dataset tonight. I'll update you.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Reconciled with Excel as well. Thanks a lot Patrick, you are a brilliant lecturer.

Comment: I'd have a side question if possible Patrick. How can I do the same but for the Omega equation?: Omega = lpm(-Data, -MAR, 1) / lpm(Data, MAR, 1). I tried with Omega = lpm(nanmean(-Returns)-MAR) ./ lpm(Returns, MAR, 2) but the results are incorrect.

Comment: The formula does not say something about a mean, does it? You should at least learn some basics of MATLAB if you use it. What about `Omega = lpm(-Results, -MAR,1) ./ lpm(Results, MAR,1)`?